# Getting User Object for forms.py

Tags: python, django

I have an app called **profiles** which just leverages the django-registration-redux module. I am trying to create a form that allows the user to edit it, with the information they already have in it, but it isn't showing up. I can get it to show up without the information, but not the profile information that already exists.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from profiles import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$', views.single, name='profile_single'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/edit/$', views.edit, name="profile_edit"),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def edit(request, username):
    instance = Profile.objects.get(user=username)
    # It would be good to have an in depth understanding of what the actual request module does
    if request.user == instance.user:
        form = ProductForm(request.POST or None, instance = instance)

    if form.is_valid():
        profile = form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = request.user
        profile.slug = slugify(form.cleaned_data['title'])
        profile.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/%s'%(user.username))
    return render_to_response("profiles/edit.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**The error that I am recieving is:**

> Exception Value:   invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'admin'

Comment: Which line is triggering the exception?

Comment: `instance = Profile.objects.get(user=username)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check `username` field of `User` model.

To do that, replace the following line:

```
instance = Profile.objects.get(user=username)
```

with:

```
instance = Profile.objects.get(user__username=username)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but I can't accept an answer for another 10 minutes. Can you please explain what `user__username` is doing or point me in the right direction to research?

Comment: @iampj, `user__username` is to make the query performed on `username` field of `user` table.

Comment: @iampj, I recommend you to read [**Lookups that span relationships**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) in Making queries - Django documentation.